# How to change menu item border color?

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

My question might me wrong.

Check the image.

[image]

The white border in the new connection. I have changed the border thickness and border brush properties, but nothing helped.

What should i do to get rid of this white border.

Code

```
<UserControl x:Class="Resources.MenuBar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Resources"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="1080">
<Grid>
    <Menu Background="#FF001E26" >
        <MenuItem Header="File" Foreground="#FF839496">
            <MenuItem Header="New Connection" Height="20" Background="#FF001E26" Click="NewConn_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Open Connection" Height="20" Background="#FF001E26" Click="OpenConn_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Comment: maybe you could show your code so we understand what's wrong?

Comment: ok, so "File" is what you want, and "New Connection" is what you have, right?

Comment: @Siegfried.V i want the white border around the new connection to be removed.

Comment: @LittleBit Okay, i will take a look.

Comment: @LittleBit Solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Siegfried.V Thanks for your Effort.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Padding="1">
    <TextBox Width="200" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" Text="New Connection"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: Same issue. The link @littlebit provided is what i want.. i am trying that solution.